# 2 div layout issue

Tags: css, html

I have a webpage with links down the left hand side of the page in a div that is floating left. I then have content to the right of that that is in a div floating right. The problem I'm having is that when the page is resized the content moves below the links.

I have tired putting the whole page in a wrapper div but when I did the links stopped working and I could not position the content where I needed too.

Here is the css for the wrapper div

```css
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    min-width:960px;
}
```

Comment: jsbin  ,,,,something .......?

Comment: maring: 0 auto; does the same as margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

Comment: You'd either have to use percentages for widths or make responsive version for smaller screens.

Comment: thanks meo but that still does nothing to fix my code

Comment: @TheAce - this is what we also ask you. Please provide some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floated elements will behave in that manner, since they're out of the page flow.

What you probably are looking for is a [fluid two column layout](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/two-liquid/).

Comment: This appears to have worked for the most part thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best way to go over the window resize issue is do like wordpress and even this site do: put balnk resizable margins around the page and make all the content fixed width.

"Liquid" style (with percents etc.) is cool but doesn't really look right most times, so the best thing is to build your page a little narrower than the full window and let different brawsers just change the margin size.

To do so I actually style the very html tag givin it a fixed width like 1000px or whatever and then margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; to keep it always centered.

EDIT:

Put this in your css

```
html {

width:66em;

margin-left:auto;

margin-right:auto;

}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Could you provide and example'

Comment: see the edit, put that in the css, you'll have your content centered in the window but it won't resize if the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are giving the divs fixed widths so the first step is to change the widths of the divs to % or em.

Do this full screen to begin with, I would even go as far as creating a blank page with no content what so ever, just give the divs a different background colo(u)r. Do this as you then know the width of the content isn't interfering.

I would also float both divs to the left and maybe position them relatively to begin with.